# cómo hago lo mismo con el return que con el print

Tags: python, string

tengo una duda, quiero iterar sobre una cadena e imprimir todas sus letras, algo sencillo, lo logré hacer con un print, pero cuándo intento con el return me corta el ciclo y me imprime solo la primer letra, cómo hago para que me imprima todos sus elementos?

mi código es este:

```
def stringporteclado(string):
    string=input("ingrese un string")
    for elem in string:
        return (elem)
print(stringporteclado("hola"))
```

Comment: La pregunta aquí es: ¿Qué pretendes retornar, una lista con cada letra como elemento? Cuando la ejecución de una función llega a un `return` se sale de la misma, esto es así en todos los lenguajes de programación y por qué no, Python.

Comment: se llama return de retorna. una vez la funcion llege a esta palabra finaliza la ejecucion devolviendo el valor

Comment: sí pretendiera retornar por ejemplo, una nueva cadena con cada elemento de la cadena"string" impreso en vertical, tal cúal lo hace el print, cómo lo haría?

Comment: Primero creas la cadena, luego la retornas

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
def stringporteclado(string):
    #string=input("ingrese un string")
    # almacenara el resultado
    resultado=""
    for elem in string:
        # asignamos a resultado el valor mas un salto de linea
        resultado+= elem +"\n"
    return resultado
print(stringporteclado("hola"))
```

o puedes crear un arreglo:

```
def stringporteclado(string):
    #string=input("ingrese un string")
    # creamos una lista haciendo una division del string
    resultado=list(string)
    # unimos, pero separando los resultado por salto de linea
    return "\n".join(resultado)
print(stringporteclado("hola"))
```